# ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action . This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path

Tags: ansible

I've got an Ansible Collections in my Ansible playbook as follows:

```
- name: Create a profile for the user
  community.windows.win_user_profile:
    username: test
    name: test
    state: present
```

and the collection is installed via

```
ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.windows
```

so I can see it at ~/.ansible/collections.

However I keep getting:

```
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'community.windows.win_user_profile'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.
```

I've also copied it alongside the playbook just in case but still get the same error message.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd guess you're on ansible 2.9 and trying to use 2.10 behavior

Answer (score 12):

I got the same error with Ansible 2.9 on Ubuntu 20.04 after install `community.general`. The solution in this case was installing `ansible.posix`

```
ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.posix
```

as this contains the `mount` module https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/mount_module.html

Answer (score 3):

ansible 2.9 uses collections different.
One way is to add them to the top:

```
---
- hosts: all
  collections:
    - community.windows
```

and then later use:

```
- name: Create a profile for the user
  win_user_profile:
    username: test
    name: test
    state: present
```

for reference:

- [Use Ansible Collections](https://thenewstack.io/tutorial-use-ansible-collections-to-help-configure-and-manage-more-complex-systems/)
- [collections are backwardcompatible](https://github.com/ansible-community/community-topics/issues/50)

Dirty:
dont do this, but it works.

```bash
ansible-config dump |grep DEFAULT_MODULE_PATH
```

and copy them there (example replace path and name)...

```bash
cp -p  ~/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/system/sudoers.py ./library/
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two Windows collections: community and Supported. I know that's confusing :(

Looks like you've installed `ansible.windows`, though you are using `community.windows`

The fix is:

`ansible-galaxy collection install community.windows`

Answer (score 0):

Adding below details to your question would be helpful

1. Ansible host operating system
2. Ansible version

I guess, this is error is specific to ansible version. I guess you are using ansible 2.9 version or lower version. whereas, Installing collections with ansible-galaxy is only supported in ansible 2.9+.

Reference link : https://galaxy.ansible.com/ansible/windows ( look into 'Note' section )

You can upgrade your ansible version and give a try.

Reference link : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#upgrading-from-2-9-or-earlier-to-2-10