# Applying Back Up Policy Ansible Azure

Tags: azure, ansible, backup

I am creating a backup policy and it states this error.

ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'azure_rm_backvmuppolicy'. This often indi                                                                                                             cates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to be in '/home/azureuser/10.yml': line 4, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

tasks:
- name: Create VM Backup Policy
^ here

My Code is:

- name: The play
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:

  - name: Create VM Backup Policy
    azure_rm_backvmuppolicy:
    name: 'BackupPolicytest'
    vault_name: 'testing236'
    resource_group: 'rg-automation'
    time: '18:00'
    weekdays: ['Monday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']
    weeks: ['First', 'Fourth']
    months: ['February', 'November']
    count: 4
    state: present

Comment: Please take a moment to read the formatting guide: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and [edit] your question accordingly. Now on your issue, this often indicates that you haven't installed the proper collection as documented in the notes of the module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_vmbackuppolicy_module.html#azure-azcollection-azure-rm-vmbackuppolicy-module-create-or-delete-azure-vm-backup-policy

Comment: [ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action . This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66335800/error-couldnt-resolve-module-action-this-often-indicates-a-misspelling-miss)